# Convert vector of lists into vector of vectors

Tags: list, vector, clojure

I have the following data in a .txt file:

```
1|John Smith|123 Here Street|456-4567
2|Sue Jones|43 Rose Court Street|345-7867
3|Fan Yuhong|165 Happy Lane|345-4533
```

I get the data and convert it to a vector using the following code:

```
(def custContents (slurp "cust.txt"))
(def custVector (clojure.string/split custContents #"\||\n"))
(def testing (into [] (partition 4 custVector )))
```

Which gives me the following vector:

```
[(1 John Smith 123 Here Street 456-4567) (2 Sue Jones 43 Rose Court Street 
345-7867) (3 Fan Yuhong 165 Happy Lane 345-4533)]
```

I would like to convert it into a vector of vectors like this:

```
[[1 John Smith 123 Here Street 456-4567] [2 Sue Jones 43 Rose Court Street 
345-7867] [3 Fan Yuhong 165 Happy Lane 345-4533]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do it slightly differently, so you first break it up into lines, then process each line.  It also makes the regex simpler:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:require
    [clojure.string :as str] ))

(def data
"1|John Smith|123 Here Street|456-4567
2|Sue Jones|43 Rose Court Street|345-7867
3|Fan Yuhong|165 Happy Lane|345-4533")

  (let [lines       (str/split-lines data)
        line-vecs-1 (mapv #(str/split % #"\|" ) lines)
        line-vecs-2 (mapv #(str/split % #"[|]") lines)]
    ...)
```

with result:

```
lines => ["1|John Smith|123 Here Street|456-4567" 
          "2|Sue Jones|43 Rose Court Street|345-7867" 
          "3|Fan Yuhong|165 Happy Lane|345-4533"]

line-vecs-1 => 
   [["1" "John Smith" "123 Here Street" "456-4567"]
    ["2" "Sue Jones" "43 Rose Court Street" "345-7867"]
    ["3" "Fan Yuhong" "165 Happy Lane" "345-4533"]]

line-vecs-2 => 
   [["1" "John Smith" "123 Here Street" "456-4567"]
    ["2" "Sue Jones" "43 Rose Court Street" "345-7867"]
    ["3" "Fan Yuhong" "165 Happy Lane" "345-4533"]]
```

Note that there are 2 ways of doing the regex.  `line-vecs-1` shows a regex where the pipe character is escaped in the string.  Since regex varies on different platform (e.g. on Java one would need "\|"), `line-vecs-2` uses a regex class of a single character (the pipe), which sidesteps the need for escaping the pipe.

---

***Update***

Other Clojure Learning Resources:

- [Brave Clojure](https://www.braveclojure.com/)
- [Clojure CheatSheet](http://jafingerhut.github.io/cheatsheet/clojuredocs/cheatsheet-tiptip-cdocs-summary.html)
- [ClojureDocs.org](https://clojuredocs.org/)
- [Clojure-Doc.org](http://clojure-doc.org/) (similar but different)

Comment: I can see how this would be better. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
> (mapv vec testing)

=> [["1" "John Smith" "123 Here Street" "456-4567"]
    ["2" "Sue Jones" "43 Rose Court Street" "345-7867"]
    ["3" "Fan Yuhong" "165 Happy Lane" "345-4533"]]
```