# Saving text file info into clojure data structure

Tags: data-structures, clojure

Got a question that I was looking for some help on. I've got a text file with entries in the following format

Jessica|23|12 west street|416-234-7584

Stuart|19|827 goldberg street|416-323-3262

Rob|45|723 wellington street|416-372-9172
etc...

I want to do some tasks with these entries, however I must first load the file into some appropriate data structure. I was thinking vectors may be the way to go but am not sure.

I'm completely new to clojure, so I was wondering if someone could guide me.

Comment: You can see a good start at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49593195/convert-vector-of-lists-into-vector-of-vectors

Comment: alan's answer to the question he linked to looks like it's exactly the answer for this question. let me know if this does not help and I'll  unlink the answer

Comment: You can use `(line-seq (clojure.java.io/reader filename))` to load the lines in your file into memory as a collection of strings, then use something like `clojure.string/split` or `re-seq` to break each string up into its individual elements. Best of luck.